# CASE Statement with a JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to select the winners of a race from an event by the specific competition they entered, for example.

The `competition` table

```
competition_ID, eventss_ID, competitor_ID, stageName, roundNo, startTime, finisheTime, judges_ID
```

The `eventss` table

```
 eventss_ID, eventsName, noOfStages, eventsDate, entryFee, venue_ID, judges_ID
```

The results I want are;

```
Event        RoundNo       competitior_ID     Competiton Winner
swimming       1                COM101            1st Place
swimming       1                COM213            2nd Place
swimming       2                COM101            1st Place
swimming       2                COM234            2nd Place
golf           1                COM654            1st Place
golf           1                COM874            2nd Place
```

Query I tried:

```
        SELECT * 

            ,CASE
            WHEN finshTime = (SELECT MIN(finshTime) FROM competition) THEN '1st Place'
            WHEN finshTime = (SELECT MAX(finshTime) FROM competition) THEN '2nd Place'

       ELSE 'Draw'

       END [Competition Winner]

       FROM competition

       JOIN eventss on eventss.eventss_ID = competition.eventss_ID

       GROUP BY competition.roundNo
```

Comment: Are there only two competitors in each round?

Comment: yes, but future development would require more

Comment: Is the finish time the finishtime - starttime? What's the point of starttime?

Comment: the startTime could be used for a football match for example

Comment: finishTime is the time the race ended, I realise golf was a bad choice to put in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably work to produce the desired output but it's hard to tell without proper sample data.

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eventss_ID, roundNo ORDER BY finishTime) RN
    FROM competition) 
, CTE2 AS (
    SELECT *
        , CASE (SELECT finishTime FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1 AND eventss_ID = c.eventss_ID AND roundNo = c.roundNO) - (SELECT finishTime FROM CTE WHERE RN = 2 AND eventss_ID = c.eventss_ID AND roundNo = c.roundNO)
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Draw'
            ELSE CASE RN 
                WHEN 1 THEN '1st Place' 
                ELSE '2nd Place' END END Drawn
    FROM CTE c
    WHERE RN IN (1, 2))
SELECT e.eventsName [Event], CTE2.RoundNo, CTE2.competitor_ID, CTE2.Drawn [Competition Winner]
FROM eventss e
JOIN CTE2 ON CTE2.eventss_ID = e.eventss_ID
ORDER BY e.eventsName, CTE2.roundNo, CTE2.Drawn
```

Note: I'm making the assumption that "finishtime" is stored as TIME or DATETIME. If it's stored as something else, this won't work.

EDIT: In the case of more than two people tied for first place, or in the case of a tie for second place, this query should work...

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eventss_ID, roundNo ORDER BY finishTime) RN
    FROM competition) 
, tiesforfirst AS (
    SELECT *
        , '1st Place' Drawn
    FROM CTE T
    WHERE finishTime = (SELECT finishTime FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1 AND eventss_ID = T.eventss_ID AND roundNo = T.roundNo))
, tiesforsecond AS (
    SELECT *
        , '2nd Place' Drawn
    FROM CTE T
    WHERE finishTime = (SELECT finishTime FROM CTE WHERE RN = 2 AND eventss_ID = T.eventss_ID AND roundNo = T.roundNo)
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tiesforfirst WHERE eventss_ID = T.eventss_ID AND roundNo = T.roundNo) = 1)
SELECT e.eventsName [Event], tf.RoundNo, tf.competitor_ID
    , CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tiesforfirst WHERE eventss_ID = tf.eventss_ID AND roundNo = tf.roundNo) WHEN 1 THEN tf.Drawn ELSE 'Drawn 1st' END [Competition Winner]
FROM eventss e
JOIN tiesforfirst tf ON tf.eventss_ID = e.eventss_ID
UNION
SELECT e.eventsName [Event], tf.RoundNo, tf.competitor_ID
    , CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tiesforsecond WHERE eventss_ID = tf.eventss_ID AND roundNo = tf.roundNo) WHEN 1 THEN tf.Drawn ELSE 'Drawn 2nd' END [Competition Winner]
FROM eventss e
JOIN tiesforsecond tf ON tf.eventss_ID = e.eventss_ID
ORDER BY e.eventsName, roundNo
```

Comment: sorry it's stored as a decimel

Comment: I should also note that if there's more than two competitors that tie or there's a tie for second place, this will not produce all of the competitors in that tie. I can modify this if it's necessary to account for that.

Comment: Edited to account for multiple ties. (In the  case of multiple ties for first place, there would be no "second place", only multiple "first place")